# Which one is the more efficient way of use an array's size? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, algorithm, function, kotlin, memory

I have to iterate through a whole array and filter something specific using it's size and i started to think that the second approach might save some processing power and memory. Any thoughts on which one is better and why?

**1st Approach**

```
override fun functionA(query: String) {
        Items = startItems.filter { entity ->
            entity.functionB(query)
        }
    }
```

entity class

```
override fun functionB(query: String): Boolean {
        queryWords = query.splitWords()
        var words = queryWords.size
        queryWords.doSomething()
        return words == 0
    }
```

**2nd Approach**

```
override fun functionA(query: String) {
        val queryWords = query.splitWords()
        val querySize = queryWords.size
        Items = startItems.filter { entity ->
            entity.functionB(queryWords, querySize)
        }
    }
```

entity class

```
override fun functionB(queryWords: List<String>, size: Int): Boolean {
        var words = size
        queryWords.doSomething()
        return words == 0
    }
```

My first tought was that i might save a couple operations(CPU wise) by calling it at the top and passing queryWord and size as parameters(2nd Approach) instead of obtaining them every time(The array of startItems will get bigger with time, at the moment it has >180 objects)

Comment: I don't understand what's the point of this filtering. Query is the same for all items, so filter always returns either all items or none of them.

Comment: Your second approach is better since you only call ``splitWords()`` and allocate a ``List`` once, instead of once for every item in `startItems`. As for whether it matters at all, you'd have to benchmark it!

Comment: @broot i have to use this filtering for a more complex compose search function that uses an entity defined function. The top level filter is for any object that implements an interface

Comment: @cactustictacs i tought of it too, i might benchmark it, performance wise it worked perfectly on an emulator on a weak office laptop

Comment: Honestly performance isn't going to come into it, unless you're working with extremely large collections (a number with lots of zeroes on the end) or extremely constrained resources (like a very small amount of memory, e.g. if you're running a lot of services that need to be very lightweight because they add up). If your laptop's running an emulator then it's already more than capable of creating a handful of extra lists! It's good to be neat and efficient if it's not making your life harder (or it's worth that compromise) - it's not really complicating things in this case, so it's up to you